# Node and Mongoose - Not reconnecting if mongod was not running when first tried to connect

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Im **using docker-composer and Im finding issues with execution order of services**. The main issue **happens when my express app tries to connect to mongod but this is not yet ready**.

The **issue can be reproduced easily by running first the nodejs application but not mongod** (manually forcing this case).

My **app uses mongoose and try to establish connection to mongod**. Because **mongod is not up and running, the app throws an error about it**.

```
$ nodemon server/app.js 
24 Apr 21:42:05 - [nodemon] v1.7.0
24 Apr 21:42:05 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
24 Apr 21:42:05 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
24 Apr 21:42:05 - [nodemon] starting `node server/app.js`
Listening on port 8000
disconnected
connection error: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
```

**Starting mongod later seems to reconnect**.

```
24 Apr 21:51:28 - [nodemon] v1.7.0
24 Apr 21:51:28 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
24 Apr 21:51:28 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
24 Apr 21:51:28 - [nodemon] starting `node server/app.js`
Listening on port 8000
disconnected
connection error: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
connected
reconnected
```

Despite of that, **operations that require access to mongo will not come through**... neither error is shown

[image]

This is the code to connect to mongo using mongoose:

```
// Starting mongo
mongoose.connect(config.database, {
                                    server:{
                                            auto_reconnect:true,
                                            reconnectTries: 10,
                                            reconnectInterval: 5000,
                                    }
                                });

// Listening for connection
var mongo = {};
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('connected', console.error.bind(console, 'connected'));
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.on('close', console.error.bind(console, 'connection close.'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("We are alive");
});
db.on('reconnected', function(){
    console.error('reconnected');   
});
db.on('disconnected', console.error.bind(console, 'disconnected'));
```

And here is the route that will try to get data from mongo but fail.

```
router.post('/auth', function(req, res){

    User.findOne({name: req.body.name})
        .then(function(user){

            if(!user)
            {
                res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
            }
            ...
```

**How can I recover from running nodejs before mongo is ready?**.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I created separate function only for mongoose connect method:

```
const connect = () => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        reconnectInterval: 500,
        poolSize: 10,
    });
};
```

I'm calling it at the same start. I also added Event Handler for `error` event:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('[MongoDB] Something went super wrong!', e);
    setTimeout(() => {
        connect();
    }, 10000);
});
```

If mongoose fails to connect because MongoDB is not running, error event handler is fired and setTimeout schedules "custom" reconnect.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take before `mongod` is ready? Because it seems like this is an edge case issue, where `mongod` might take a couple of seconds to get ready; and when mongoose is connected it serves requests as expected. Just trying to understand why the slight delay (probably a only a few seconds) is necessary to resolve?

But here is a solution anyway:

You could set up an express middleware to check if mongoose is ready and throw an error if not:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if (mongoose.Connection.STATES.connected === mongoose.connection.readyState){
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(503).send({success:false, message: 'DB not ready' });
    }
});
```

This should go before you inject your router.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Mongoose 5+. I was able to get this working by creating a retry function using set timeout.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {
  MONGO_USERNAME,
  MONGO_PASSWORD,
  MONGO_HOSTNAME,
  MONGO_PORT,
  MONGO_DB,
  MONGO_DEBUG,
  MONGO_RECONNECT_TRIES,
  MONGO_RECONNECT_INTERVAL,
  MONGO_TIMEOUT_MS,
} = process.env;

if (MONGO_DEBUG) {
  console.log(`********* MongoDB DEBUG MODE *********`);
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
}

const DB_OPTIONS = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  reconnectTries: MONGO_RECONNECT_TRIES,
  reconnectInterval: MONGO_RECONNECT_INTERVAL,
  connectTimeoutMS: MONGO_TIMEOUT_MS,
};

const DB_URL = `mongodb://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}?authSource=admin`;

// Initialize conenction retry counter
let reconnectTriesAlready = 1;

// Connect to database with timeout and retry
const connectWithRetry = () => {
  mongoose.connect(DB_URL, DB_OPTIONS).then(() => {
    // Connected successfully
    console.log('********* MongoDB connected successfully *********');
    // Reset retry counter
    reconnectTriesAlready = 1;
  }).catch(err => {
    // Connection failed
    console.error(`********* ERROR: MongoDB connection failed ${err} *********`)
    // Compare retries made already to maximum retry count
    if (reconnectTriesAlready <= DB_OPTIONS.reconnectTries) {
      // Increment retry counter
      reconnectTriesAlready = reconnectTriesAlready + 1;
      // Reconnect retries made already has not exceeded maximum retry count
      console.log(`********* MongoDB connection retry after ${MONGO_RECONNECT_INTERVAL / 1000} seconds *********`)
      // Connection retry
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, MONGO_RECONNECT_INTERVAL)
    } else {
      // Reconnect retries made already has exceeded maximum retry count
      console.error(`********* ERROR: MongoDB maximum connection retry attempts have been made already ${DB_OPTIONS.reconnectTries} stopping *********`)
    }
  })
}

connectWithRetry();
```